# Unable to get a solution on OPL, CPLEX

Tags: cplex, opl

I am running fairly parge problems on CPLEX which were not being solved, hence to make things easier I thought of using some heuristics and solve it part by part instead. My current part problem has the following statistics :
Constraints : 149,348
Variables : 277,582
Binary :  1,187
Other  : 276,395
Non Zero Coefficients : 3,540,328

This stops without reaching a solution with the following Engine log given below.

I checked the Profiler tab. The ROOT Peak Memory is 1,953,951,744 (100%). There are several other rows in the Profiler for the variables. I am not sure of what this implies.

The problem has a valid solution that I can solve manually so it should give a result.

If someone wants to give the code a try please ping me and we can discuss.

Any suggestions on what else to look for

```
---------------------------- ENGINE LOG------------------
CPXPARAM_Emphasis_Memory                         1
CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_AbsMIPGap                0.0001
CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_File                       2
CPXPARAM_Emphasis_MIP                            2
Found incumbent of value 0.000000 after 0.00 sec. (7.55 ticks)
Aggregator has done 26901 substitutions...
Aggregator has done 69801 substitutions...
Tried aggregator 2 times.
MIP Presolve eliminated 18091 rows and 17732 columns.
Aggregator did 129652 substitutions.
Reduced MIP has 1605 rows, 130198 columns, and 1920419 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 749 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 8.39 sec. (25691.97 ticks)
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Reduced MIP has 1605 rows, 130198 columns, and 1920419 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 749 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 0.53 sec. (547.10 ticks)

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    9.09 sec. (26422.83 ticks)
Parallel b&c, 16 threads:
  Real time             =    0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
  Sync time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
  Wait time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
                          ------------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    9.09 sec. (26422.83 ticks)

------------------The solutions tab--------------------------------
// solution (optimal) with objective 0
// Quality Incumbent solution:
// MILP objective                                 0.0000000000e+00
// MILP solution norm |x| (Total, Max)            0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00
// MILP solution error (Ax=b) (Total, Max)        0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00
// MILP x bound error (Total, Max)                0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00
// MILP x integrality error (Total, Max)          0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00
// MILP slack bound error (Total, Max)            0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00
// 

Xbmt = [[[0]]
             [[0]]
             [[0]]
   ....and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Engine log we can read that Cplex found the optimal solution

If you want to Check that the solution you Build by yourself is valid you could use warm Start

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoowarmstartapi.mod

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for the response. The solution that CPLEX has given is all 0 as you can see in my post at the bottom, the values of the variables like Xbmt etc are all 0.                                                 The solution I get manually is not necessarily an optimised solution it is "a feasible solution" which I have done in other 3D software of the domain(not optimiser). But it implies that CPLEX should have reached a similar solution at least if not a better one.